# Why is the router undefined although I injected the router correctly in Angular?

Tags: angular, onclick, navigation, router

I have following variable:

```
  images = [
    {title: "Edit order", img: "./buttons/edit.png", clickHandler: this.onEdit},
 ]
```

and the function

```
  onEdit(){
    if(this.orderDetail){
      console.log("edited");
      this.router.navigate(['/orders/edit']);
    }else return;
  }
```

which I use as follows in my html.component:

```
<div class="images" *ngFor="let imageObj of images" [title]="imageObj.title">
   <img [src]="imageObj.img" [alt]="imageObj.title" (click)="imageObj.clickHandler()">
</div>
```

But somehow it does not work correctly. I get the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

I did import the router and inject it correctly. The router works but not in this case but why?

SOLUTION:

Use an arrow function, in which you return the function you want to call:

```
  images = [
    {title: "Edit order", img: "./buttons/edit.png", clickHandler: () => {
        return this.onEdit
    },
 ]
```

Comment: Please include the component constructor and the import - and make sure theres a RouterModule imported in the module the component is inside of.

Comment: @MikeS. I included all now

Comment: That's not what I meant, I meant the module that your component is part of - that one has to have a routermodule imported

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with the router. Looks like a scoping issue. Do you still get the error if you change (click)="imageObj.clickHandler()" to (click)="onEdit()"..?

Comment: @MikeOne yes, then it does work. I think it is really a scoping issue. How would I solve it?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what your intentions are with this code. The ‘normal’ way to approach something like this is to directly call the component method (onEdit) and pass in the object you’re looping over so: (click)="onEdit(imageObject)" and then you have a reference to the thing you want to edit..

Comment: @MikeOne I have more than one button, I would have to repeat html code which I don't want to. So, is the only solution to repeat the html code and then assign to every image a clickHandler?

Comment: Every image can have the same clickhandler, or you use arrow functions to keep the scope in your component.

Comment: @MikeS. Now, it works! I used an arrow function and in this I return the function I want to call and it works quite well. Thanks!

Comment: I’m still confused at what you’re trying to do here.. what does the additional function reference give you..?

Comment: Hey, this was just an example. In the array are around 9 buttons with 9 different functions and if I would not save it in an array I would have to repeat the html code from above around 9 times which I try to avoid. Thats why I save the button name, the image src and a clickHandler such that I do not have to repeat the html code 9 times, I am not sure whether there is another approach to use less code but in this case I find my approach useful. If there is another, better way, please tell me.